Conformal Riemannian metrics on the spherical boundary of hyperbolic n-spaces
We say two Riemannian metrics $g, g'$ on $M$ conformal if there exists a function $f$ such that $g = fg'$. Now, we consider a special collection of Riemannian metrics $\{g_p\}_{p\in H}$ on the spherical boundary $S^d$ of hyperbolic $(d+1)$-space $\mathbb{H}^{d+1}$ denoted by $H$ below. The Riemannian metric $g_p$ associated to a point $p\in H$ is defined as the following: consider the inner product on the unit tangent space $T^1_pH$ induced from the hyperbolic metric on $H$ and pushforward it via $exp_p:T^1_pH\to S^d$. (Details are explained very nicely here!)
One can show that for any $\phi\in \text{Isom}(H)$ (which induces a conformal map $\phi:S^d\to S^d$) and for any $p,q\in H$ where $\phi(q)=p$, we have $\phi_*g_q=g_p$. Now my question is to figure out the ratio $\frac{g_q}{g_p}(\xi)$ where $\xi\in S^d$ i.e. figure out how $\phi$ distorted the Riemannian metrics $\{g_p\}_{p\in H}$ and show they are conformal.
I try to compute $\phi_*g_p$ explicitly, but I fail to know how the differential moves tangent vectors or the explicit formula for $g_p$. A hint from Sullivan's paper: given $p,q\in H$ and $\xi\in S^d$, consider the upper half space model with $\xi$ as origin point. Let $T$ be the parabolic transformation moving $p,q$ to the imaginary axis where $\rho=T(p),\rho'=T(q)$ and $T'$ be the dilation sending  $\rho$ to $\rho'$. Then the ratio $\frac{g_q}{g_p}(\xi)$ equals the linear derivative of $T'\circ T$ at $\xi$ which is $e^{d(\rho,\rho')}$.
Thanks for your help!
